# How to select multi lists in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'd like to select the multi lists (I mean when you click the list the color is changed from grey to pink. so when you click multi lists(other lists), I'd like to change the color of them from grey to pink.) and when you click the list again, it will change the original color. (from pink to grey).

How can I do this using class bind?

I used below code with `[class.active]` please review it and let me know the hint.

HTML:

```
<div class="list" *ngFor="let list of lists | filter: searchText; let i = index" (click)="setClickedList(i)" [class.active]="i == selectedList">
   <mat-list-item role="listitem">{{list}}</mat-list-item>
</div>
```

JS:

```
lists = ['Team Name1', 'Team Name2', 'Team Name3', 'Team Name4', 'Team Name5'];
```

CSS:

```
.list.active {
    background-color:#ff4081 !important;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: `[ngClass]="{'active':i==selectedList}"` this is how you apply class on selection. you can add more classes on other conditions separated by comma.

Comment: so when you click the list again, i want to change the color with original color. in this case, how can i add?
like this.
https://czeckd.github.io/angular-dual-listbox/demo/

Comment: `[ngClass]="{'active':i==selectedList,'inactive':yourNewConditionHERE}"` and then simply add inactive class in your css.

Comment: there `active` and `inactive` are classes?

Comment: yes they are classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Example of gray to pink and pink to gray in click event using class binding.
Html File

```
<ul class="list" [class.active]="isActive" (click)="changeActive()" *ngFor="let item of fruits">
  <li>Fruit Name :{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Typescript File

```
 public isActive: boolean = false;

 changeActive() {
    this.isActive = !this.isActive; //here iam changing flag to true to false and false to true
    console.log("Is Active Value",this.isActive);
  }
```

css file

```
.list.active {
    background-color:#ff4081 !important;
    color: white;
}

.list{
    background-color:gray !important;
    color: white;
}
```

Here iam doing sample data please replace your data and variable like.
iam tested perfect working. please try one once if any error please let me know.

here is the output window.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[class.active]="i == selectedList"`, try `[ngClass]="{'active': i == selectedList}"`

Comment: so when you click the list again, i want to change the color with original color. in this case, how can i add? like this. czeckd.github.io/angular-dual-listbox/demo

Comment: You could have an array of booleans for each item of the list and just toggle the values checked/unchecked. In this case the ngClass would look somthing like this `[ngClass]="{'active': checkedItems[i]}"`